# Dynamically assign a subdomain that is not related to a folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I need to create a sub-domain dynamically. What my code does is load html code from DB then displays it.

There are no sub folders or anything like that. I want a url that looks like this `XXXXXX.com/loadfile.php?website=test` to  look like `test.XXXXXX.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as basic as this should do the trick:

```
<?php
// assuming you have $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] reliably set and available
// i.e. something like $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'XXXXXX.com';

$subdomain = $_GET['website'] . '.' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

You might want to validate the input etc.

Comment: I sorry but I am not sure what you mean. Currently I am running this on a local host just as I code it. how would I implement this. I don't think I understand the code completely. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems to be realy easy.

The code I used was:

$website = array_shift((explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])));

This allowed me to get the sub domain on its own. Then sent the query with the name. I left this in the index.php file so you could type the sub-domain and not have to add the file "/example.php". Then if someone displayed the domain I had a if statement to check for this. It would then echo out the index content.

Thanks Daren Chandisingh for getting me on my way. Huge help. No idear about the whole sub-domain thing.